# Magento2 DOB Customer attribute Save

Tags: magento2

While customer creation , i need to store dob attribute for customer.which is not saving. facing issue like,

SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'customer_entity.value_id' in 'field list', query was: SELECT `customer_entity`.`value_id` FROM `customer_entity` WHERE (attribute_id='11' AND entity_id='199')

meanwhile,if i added custom date attribute in customer entity it get saved.
Any one have any idea about it.
Thanks in advance.
I am storing custom attributes as given below,

```
    $data = []; //Array of attributes with key as attribute code 
    $customer = $this->customerModel->load($customerId);
    $customerData = $customer->getDataModel();
    $customerResource = $this->customerAttrFactory->create();
    foreach ($data as $attrCode => $attrValue):
        $customerData->setCustomAttribute($attrCode, $attrValue);
        $customer->updateData($customerData);
        $customerResource->saveAttribute($customer, $attrCode);
    endforeach;
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to save dob as an attribute.
Customer entity table has dob field so we can set it through customer model as given below.

```
    $websiteId = $this->storeManager->getWebsite()->getWebsiteId();
    $customer = $this->customerFactory->create();
    $customer->setWebsiteId($websiteId);
    $data['dob'] = $formData['dob'];
    $customer->setData($data);
    $customer->save();
```